Подключение к базе срабатывает через раз
Есть несколько докер контейнеров. С бд и пхп.
Пароли от бд передаются через переменную окружения из docker compose
Когда я захожу на страницу иногда получается так что при выполнении запроса к бд падает ошибка
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pet'@'172.18.0.7' (using password: YES)
т.е 2-5 раз обновляю страницу все ок работает, потом падает эта ошибка, потом обновляю может опять работать, может опять падать ошибка, закономерности никакой нет. Как и где можно посмотреть причину запрета юзера и как это исправить?
При этом есть контейнер с нодой и там по такому же принципу периодически проскакивает данная ошибка

ну начните с того чтобы логировать пароль, используемый для подключения

Данные которые используются при подключении каждый раз одни и те же, вывел их в текстовый файл, ничего не меняется при каждом обновлении и даже в момент падения

было б неплохо код ещё увидеть
